# PLL power supply filtering

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, embedded, pll

On [page 7 of the "SAM4E schematic checklist"](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42231-SAM4E-Schematic-Checklist_AP-Note_AT06068.pdf), Atmel recommends the following filtering circuitry on the core and PLL supply voltages:
[image]

(It's worth nothing that VDDOUT is the 1.2 volt output of an internal regulator)

I have the following questions about the filtering on VDDPLL:

- Why does the PLL require an inductor whereas VDDCORE does not?  Is it so that a steady current is supplied?
- What's the purpose of the 1 ohm resistor connected to the 4.7u capacitor on VDDPLL?  Why not directly connect the capacitor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PLL is sensitive to noise on its power input pin in a way that the core really is not (The PLL is essentially analogue at least as far as the VCO and squarer are concerned, so ANY noise will impact the performance), the core just needs the supply to stay within an acceptable range.

The 10uH and caps form a filter to massively reduce the high frequency noise at the PLL pin.

The resistor serves to damp the resonance of the 10uH inductor and the caps on the pll pin which could otherwise actually increase the noise level at some frequencies, you do NOT want too much Q here.

Answer (score -1):

Compute dampening resistor (your one ohm) using the math sqrt(L/C).

Assuming the L is 10uH, and cap is 4.7uF, you have sqrt(2) or 1.414 ohms.